# Building CSS from SASS using Node / Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, compass-sass

Ok, I am building an asset builder app using Node / Grunt. The idea I have is to be able to manage different projects and concat / compass / minify the output.

Now I have most of what I have done so far working. I can concat my JS files (no minify let) but I am having a little bit of an issue on how to deal with my SASS files.

I have used the Grunt teams contrib compass task to compile SASS down to CSS. However how best should I concat the files?

Should I use the concat with Grunt to build a single SASS file, then build that down to CSS? If so how best to build the watch call to watch all files to see for changes but only build that one SASS/CSS file?

Or would it be best to have one 'master' SASS file that just uses the import power of SASS to build the single CSS file? If so again how should I use Grunt to build just that one file but watch all SASS files for changes?

I should also add here that I am using compass to minify the CSS file.

Here is my Grunt file as it stands now :

```
  module.exports = function (grunt) {

   grunt.initConfig({

    pkg:grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {
        options: {
          separator: ';'
        },
        dist: {
          src: ['js/*.js'],
          dest: 'assets/built.js'
        }
    },
    compass: {
        dist: { 
            options: {
              sassDir: 'sass',
              cssDir: 'assets',
              environment: 'development',
              outputStyle: 'compressed'
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        files:['js/*.js','sass/*.scss'],
        tasks:['concat','compass']  
    }

}); 

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

    grunt.registerTask('default',['concat','compass']);
  }
```

All ideas are very welcome,

Thanks

Glenn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its ok, I have come up with a solution. I have moved from the compass plugin to the SASS. I tell grunt to watch all SCSS files, as above and just tell it to build a single css file with the SASS plugin.

Like so :

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({

    pkg:grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {
        options: {},
        dist: {
          src: ['js/*.js'],
          dest: 'assets/master.js'
        }
    },
    sass: {
        dist: { 
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                'assets/master.css' : 'sass/to_build.scss'
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        files:['js/*.js','sass/*.scss'],
        tasks:['concat','sass'] 
    }

}); 

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.registerTask('default',['concat','sass']);
}
```

I hope this might help someone else.

Thanks

Glenn.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try utilizing partials?

http://sass-lang.com/guide

Use partials and have the compass task create any css based off *.scss. (note this excludes the partials _*.scss) This should handle your concat issue just as if you were utilizing a gui like compass.app or scout without the need to write extra grunt configuration tasks.

Grunt + Compass:
http://ryanchristiani.com/add-compass-to-your-grunt-task/